# 'fgets()' in a 'for' loop asks for input just once

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, fgets, parallel-arrays

I'm making a program which asks the user to type a list of 5 products and their price. Both the names and the prices are stored in two parallel arrays which will be later be used together to output the price of each product. The function used to ask for input and store the information is the following:

```
void NamesAndPrices(char products[5][41], float prices[5]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Type the name of the product: ");
        fgets(products[i], 41, stdin);
        strtok(products[i], "\n");
        printf("Type the price: ");
        scanf("%f", &prices[i]);
    }
}
```

It receives two arguments: the arrays where the information will be stored, both declared in the `main()` function:

```
int main() {
    char products[5][41];
    float prices[5];
    NamesAndPrices(products, prices);
    return 0;
}
```

When the code is compiled and run, it asks for the name of the product only once. Here's an example:

```
Type the name of the product: 40 x 60 Rug
Type the price: 39.99
Type the name of the product: Type the price: 0
Type the name of the product: Type the price: 0
Type the name of the product: Type the price: 0
Type the name of the product: Type the price: 0
```

Why is `fgets()` ignored after the first execution of the statements?

Comment: Classic: your `scanf()` leaves a newline in the input buffer, `fgets()` therefore finds an "empty line"

Comment: In general, don't mix `scanf()` (which **parses** input) with plain input functions. `fgets()` doesn't "ask" for anything, it just reads what's there. You might want to read my [beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).